# jqgrid setSelect function issue

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

In this function, its default value `all` is never returned:

```
$grid->setSelect("title", "SELECT  DISTINCT field1,field2 FROM tmp ORDER BY field1;", true, true, true, array(""=>"all"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the default value will work in search mode and not with edit mode

Comment: I still dont know since im facing the same problem, ill get back to u when i find a solution, i already posted my question on jqGrid forum http://www.trirand.net/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&m=7028&#post7028

Comment: The link http://www.trirand.net/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&t=651 provided by Pilot in my post http://www.trirand.net/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&m=7028&#post7028 solved my problem, hope will solve urs too